# How do you reference variables from another class?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to call variables from another class into my function. I have tried numerous ways, and keep getting errors. Here's a snippit of my code:

```
- (void) planning: (Deliver*) m :(Car*) n{
    int cost = 0;
    Cost = Deliver.street - Car.avenue;

}
```

The problem is I want to get variables `street` and `avenue` from Deliver and Car class, but I get an error saying  "property 'avenue' not found in class Car" on this line `Cost = Deliver.street - Car.avenue;` I also get this problem with Deliver too.

I have tried adding `[Car avenue];` inside the function, but it still doesn't fix this problem. I have already added street and avenue in @property and @synthesis in Deliver and Car classes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The current compilation unit needs to both know of the property, and that the class `Car` isn't just a figment of someone's imagination.  #import it's header properly, and make sure that you have a public-facing property called `avenue' declared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (void) planning: (Deliver*) m :(Car*) n{
    int cost = 0;
    cost = m.street - n.avenue;
}
```

There are a couple of things worth noting about your code snippet.  First, it doesn't actually do anything, since it stores its work in a local variable (`cost`) and that variable is not returned; `cost` will be thrown away at the end of the method.  Second, you haven't named your second method argument.  More conventional is to use a name that describes the purpose of both the method and each of its arguments, like:

```
- (int) calculateCostToDeliverTo:(Deliver*)destination withCar:(Car*)car {
    int cost = destination.street - car.avenue;
    return cost;
}
```

Comment: What!! No way. I thought m and n were used to what's taking in. Nevertheless, I remember how it was done in C and java now. Thanks Seamus.

Comment: Nice edit, though Objective-C doesn't have *named arguments* (which implies optionality).   Yes, it'll work with arrays.  Arguments in Objective-C work just like arguments in C, really.